# Script to apply two cell style in single row

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

I frequently work on financial document more than 100 tables, I come across tables where there are four cell styles

1. **Thick rule Left aligned** (For first cell in a random row)
2. **Thick rule right aligned** for rest of cell in row
3. **Thin rule left aligned** (for first cell in a row)
4. **Thin rule  Right aligned** for rest of cell in a row

So, I need script when i will select row it should apply two cell style (**Thick rule left aligned** for first cell and **Thick rule right aligned** for rest of other cells).

Important thing I cannot create a cell style in a template. Please check the attached image and help me overcome.

[image]

Comment: I need Indesign script

Comment: GD.SE is not a place to request free scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Imho you don't need a script.

Just set 4 different cell styles:

1. one for left column (based on a left-aligned para style)
2. one for the rest of the cells (based on a right-aligned para style)
3. one for thin rule
4. and finally one for thick rule

Then create a table style, with cell style#1 applied to 1st column and cellstyle#2 applied to body cells. (Mind the order!)

Knowing that you can assign shortcuts to cell styles, you can easily place your cursor anywhere in a row, hit <kbd>CTRL/Command</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> to select the entire row and then use your custom shortcut to apply the cell style with the desired rule.

See example:
[image]

Comment: I am aware of what you explained above But client provides cell style 2 thick rule and 2 thin rule apart from most other header for which i assign shortcut in template can you help me to prepare script where i can just change the two cell style name in script and in single click the row should apply two styles, one for first cell only and next style for rest of other cell.. As book contains more than 100 page. So it is hard come up with shortcut for all styles like character,  paragraph and table styles.

Comment: I cannot create any custom table style in client template

Comment: Sorry, maybe you'll find someone who is willing to write a free script for you. I don't have time for that...